# CAMARA_REQUEST causing the app to crash when launching startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to launch the camera activity and send the results back to the parent activity via a Uri. When I attempt to launch the activity via a button, the program crashes as soon as I press the button.

```java
public class First_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10;
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first__page);
    }

    public void cameraClicked(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
            imageUri = data.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-05 01:41:51.857 16089-16089/skript.com.tribaltattoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: skript.com.tribaltattoo, PID: 16089
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{16ab3ff 16089:skript.com.tribaltattoo/u0a57} (pid=16089, uid=10057) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
                                                                         at skript.com.tribaltattoo.First_Page.cameraClicked(First_Page.java:39)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Additional info:
The android manifest includes:

```
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{16ab3ff 16089:skript.com.tribaltattoo/u0a57} (pid=16089, uid=10057) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA`

Comment: It seems you forgot to require the permission to use the Camera.

Comment: I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` to the manifest (I didn't see your post first before I made the edit, so sorry). Are there additional permissions I need to set?

Comment: I don't know, since I never used the Camera. Just google to see which are the required permissions. Just keep in mind that Android 6.0+ uses a different permission requirement model, other than the Manifest declaration/s (still used in lower API Levels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Android emulator on my desktop to run the software. Apparently this was causing the issue since, if I run it on my device, it works perfectly. Apparently, the emulator can't handle camera's.